# Defining relationships and processing data within them

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have got myself a bit confused with relationships, I am not sure if I am splitting things up too much?  I am dealing with a reporting system where there can be different types of `reports`. So, I have my standard reports table and model, and within the model, I define that a report can have one report type.

```
public function reportType() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ReportType');
}
```

Now a `reportType` can be one of three different Types, lets call them A, B and C.  Each reportType collects different data.  As such, within the ReportType model, I define a has one relationship with the type it has

```
public function reportTypeA() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ReportTypeA');
}
```

So the above states that a `reportType` can have one `reportTypeA`.  I also have in this Model that it can have one reportTypeB and C.  Now within reportTypeA model, I state that reportTypeA can have one set of reportTypeAData

```
public function reportTypeAData() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ReportTypeAData');
}
```

I have the inverse relationships in all Models.  So essentially, I have

```
Report->ReportType->ReportTypeA->ReportTypeAData
                    ReportTypeB->ReportTypeBData
                                 ReportTypeBData2
                    ReportTypeC->ReportTypeCData
```

Reason I have the data models is because some reports have more than one set of data.  So the above shows that Report B has 2 sets of data, each with its own structure.

So the above works, but it seems very "waterfall" approach to me.  I will clean this up at some point to hopefully make it more structured.

This is where I am confused though, with the above approach, how can I get the data for a Report?  So in my controller, I have something like

```
$report = Report::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

This will get me the first report for the logged in User.  I can then get the report data doing something like this

```
$reportData = $report->reportType->reportTypeA->reportTypeAData->all()->toArray();
```

Which seems proper overkill having to go through all relationships.  My main problem is this, I want to chunk the data back to the frontend, so I will have something like this

```
DB::table("report_type_a_data")->chunk(100, function ($data) use ($handle) {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        // Add a new row with data
        fputcsv($handle, [
            $row->id,
            $row->name
        ]);
    }
});
```

Now obviously that will loop all data, where I only want the data for the report I am dealing with.  Additionally, when I try this, I get an error

```
You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function
```

Why am I getting this?  Any help with organising things better and how I can process a specific reports data is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To me, the `ReportType` entity seems rather obsolete. You can also implement this logic with a simple column on the `Report` entity. Either one of these entities will be responsible to connect to the different type tables, so adding another level of complexity doesn't make much sense. But maybe you have a look at table inheritance patterns to share some logic, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `orderBy()` when you use `chunk()`.

For example.

```
DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(100, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});
```

or you can use `chunkById()`.

```
DB::table('users')->where('active', false)
    ->chunkById(100, function ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            // 
        }
    });
```

Please refer to the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results)